# How to change the Thread COAP examples to work with the NRF 52840 Dongle

Tags: dongle, openthread

I am wanting to try out the COAP examples in the thread and zigbee 2.0 SDK on the NRF52840 Dongle. However, I am failing to to get it working. The original makefile would create a hex file that refused to be flashed to the dongle via the programmer app. I then thought to change the linker script of the makefile to /openthread_nrf82840_boodloader.ld. This fixed the issue of the hex file not being able to get flashed to the dongle but then the dongle would become unrecognisable to the PC.

What do I need to change so that the Thread COAP examples will work with the NRF52840 dongle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the libraries with support for USB bootloader present in PCA10059. As this dongle uses native USB support we have to enable it as well. To do so, build the libraries with the following parameter:

```
$ make -f examples/Makefile-nrf52840 USB=1 BOOTLOADER=1
```

Please see [nRF52840 Dongle Programming](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.nrf52%2Fdita%2Fnrf52%2Fdevelopment%2Fnrf52840_dongle%2Fprogramming.html&cp=2_0_4_4) for more details about how to use USB bootloader.